# Making a search by ID in friends list in Python

Tags: python, search, structure, social-networking, readfile

I am new to Python and currently searching for some internship or a job. I am currently working on a program in Python which reads a file that contains data in this shape:

```
Id;name;surname;age;gender;friends;
```

**Id** and **age** are the positive integers,

**gender** can be "male" or "female",

and **friends** is an array of numbers, separated by comma, which represent the Id's of persons who are friends with the current person. If Person1 is a friend to a Person2, it must work vice versa.

As you can see in the above example, attributes of a "Person" are separated by semicolon, and the trick is that not every person has every attribute, and of course, they differ by the number of friends. So, the first part of the task is to make a program which reads a file and creates a structure which represents a list of persons with the attributs mentioned above. I have to make a search for those persons by Id.

The second part is to make a function with two arguments (Id1, Id2) which returns True if a person with Id2 is a friend to a person with Id1. Otherwise, it returns false.

I have some ideas on my mind, but I am not sure how to realize this, since I don't know enough about Python yet. I guess the best structure for this would be a dictionary, but I am not sure how to load a file into it, since the attributes of all persons are different. I would be greatful for any help you can offer me.
Here is my attempt to write the code:

```
people = open(r"data.txt")

class People:

    id = None
    name = ''
    surname = ''
    age = None
    gender = ['male', 'female']
    friends = []
    #def people(self):
       # person = {'id': None,
           #       'name': '',
           #       'surname': '',
           #       'age': None,
            #      'gender': ['male', 'female'],
             #     'friends': []
        #          }
       # return person

    def community(self):
        comm = [People()]
        return comm

def is_friend(id1, id2):

    if (id1 in People.friends) & (id2 in People.friends):
        return True

people.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you will find the community very willing to help if you can show what you've tried and what you are stuck on. The `csv` module would help you read in your data and you should think about the appropriate data structures for your information.

Comment: I'd make a `Person` class and then just have their friends be a set of ids (ints) as an attribute of that class. Is friendship commutative?

Comment: Yes, friendship is commutative, like on the real social networks. I've also tried to make a class Person, and to read data into it, but I still didn't learn how to do it. I can upload my attempt of making the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad imho, but I'll give you a few hints:

1. the simplest datastructure for O(n) key access is indeed a dict. Note that a dict needs immutable values as keys (but that's fine since your Ids are integers), but can take anything as values. but that only works for (relatively) small datasets since it's all in memory. If you need bigger datasets and/or persistance, you want a database (key:value, relational, document, the choice is up to you).
2. Python has classes and computed attributes
3. In Python, the absence of a value is the `None` object
4. there's a `csv` files parser in the standard lib.

Now you just have to read the doc and start coding.

[edit] wrt/ your code snippet

```
class People:

    id = None
    name = ''
    surname = ''
    age = None
    gender = ['male', 'female']
    friends = []
```

Python is not Java or PHP. What you defined above are class attributes (shared by all instances of the class), you want instance attributes (defined in the `__init()` method). You should really [read the FineManual](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Also if you're using Python 2.7.x, you want your classes to inherit from `object` (historical reasons).

So your `Person` class should look something like this:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, surname, age, gender, friends=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.friends = friends or []
```

And then to create a `Person` instance:

```
person = Person(42, "John Cleese", "Archie Leach", 77, "male", [11, 1337)])




def is_friend(id1, id2):
    if (id1 in People.friends) & (id2 in People.friends):
        return True
```

A few points points here:

First: you either want to rename this function `are_friends` *or* make it a method of the `Person` class and then only pass a (single) `Person` instance (not an 'id') as argument.

Second: in Python, `&` is the bitwise operator. The logical "and" operator is spelled, well, `and`.

Third: an expression has a truth value by itself, so your `if` statement is redundant. Whenever you see something like:

```
def func():
    if <some expression>:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

you can just rewrite it as :

```
def func():
    return <some expression>
```

Or if you want to ensure `func` returns a proper boolean (`True` or `False`):

```
def func():
    return bool(<some expression>)
```

I'll stop here because I don't intend to teach you how to program. You obviously need to do *at least* the full official Python tutorial, and possibly some complete beginner tutorial too.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The file I am using is small, it has only 20 persons, so I believe it-s not that difficult task. I have tried to use a class at first, but couldn't get any further because the lack of knowledge. I will try with the csv lib, thanks.

Comment: A class here would be to model the 'person' entity. You'd store instances of this class in a dict (20 records is a toy dataset so you really obtain need anything more). You may want to encapsulate this dict in a 'PersonRepository' object responsible for populating the dict from the csv file and lookup persons by Id.  This constitute your domain model. Then you just have to write an ui (text,  command line, web or whatever) to use this model and you're done.

Comment: Who can I load the data into dictionary, if it belongs to a class? How to use the attributes of dictionary then? I tried to do this, but no data were read:    class People:

    person = {'id' : None,
    'name' : '',
    'surname' : '',
    'age' : None,
    'gender' : ['male', 'female'],
    'friends' : []
    }
    ppl = {}

People.ppl = open(r"data.txt", 'r')
People.read()
print (People.person)

Comment: Err... I guess you'll have to learn about OOP in general and how it works in Python.

Comment: I managed to make a class and load the file, and now I am trying to figure out how to make that function. Here's what I did:

Comment: `    def is_friend(id1, id2):

        p.id = id1
       # for id2 in p.friends:
        if str(id2) in p.friends:
             #print(p)
             return True
        else:
            return False `